# Laravel 5.1 querying a collection inside blade template

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade, laravel-collection

In my blade template I have the following $questions collection

```
Collection {
  #items: array:2 [
    0 => Question {
      ....
      #attributes: array:7 [
        "survey_id" => 3
        "question_num" => 0
        "question_text" => "test"
        "expected_answer" => 1
        "created_at" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        "updated_at" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
      ]
    }
    1 => Question {#318 ▶}
  ]
}
```

To check if a question_num exist I can do the following:

```
 @foreach ($questions as $question) {
     @if ($question->question_num == 0)
       {{ $question->question_text }}
     @endif 
 @endforeach
```

However is there a way I can do something like this so that I can query the collection directly without having to use a loop?

```
 {{ $questions->where('question_num','=', 0)->get('question_text', null) }}
```

Applying the where method `$questions->where('question_num','=', 0)` gives me the following result:

```
[{"survey_id":3,"question_num":0,"question_text":"test","expected_answer":1,"created_at":"2016-02-28 14:20:17","updated_at":"2016-02-28 14:20:17"}]
```

So why does it reuturn null when I chain the get method `->get('question_text', null)`

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-filter

Comment: Why doesn't the get method work?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `first()` method instead. In Laravel `get()` returns an arrayable collection